# how to update meta information of inherited moose classes?

Tags: perl, metadata, moose

I dont know if i asked that question the right way but i will try to explain.

I have a base class MyClass.pm:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

class MyClass {
    method test_it {
        for (__PACKAGE__->meta->get_all_methods){
            print $_->name . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

And another class MyOtherClass.pm:

```
use MooseX::Declare;

class MyOtherClass extends MyClass {
    method one {
        return 1;
    }

    method two {
        return 1;
    }

    method three {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And a script use_it.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use MyClass;
use MyOtherClass;

my $class = MyOtherClass->new;
my $otherclass = MyOtherClass->new;

print "MyClass can:\n";
$class->test_it;

print "MyOtherClass can:\n";
$otherclass->test_it;

exit 0;
```

Output is:

```
MyClass can:
dump
DEMOLISHALL
meta
does
new
DESTROY
BUILDALL
BUILDARGS
test_it
DOES
MyOtherClass can:
dump
DEMOLISHALL
meta
does
new
DESTROY
BUILDALL
BUILDARGS
test_it
DOES
```

So if i call test_it on MyClass the output contains as expected "test_it" alongside with some build in methods.
Calling test_it on MyOtherClass produces the same output with one, two and three missing.

How can i get a list of the methods that contains all methods of the inheriting class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `$self->meta->get_all_methods`, not `__PACKAGE__->meta->get_all_methods`. `__PACKAGE__` is bound by Perl at compile time, so it will always be `MyClass`.

Comment: <3 perl. You have your question answered by the person who practically invented Moose. \o/

Comment: No practically about it. Him and "initial commit".